# jQueryMobile pagebeforechange get destination page id

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery

I got some controls which are visible on each site. To move those controls to the page currently active, I am using the `pagebeforechange` event.

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange',function(e,data) {
  var topageid=$(data.toPage).attr('id'); //MY QUESTION IS ON THIS LINE
  console.log("Changing page to "+topageid);
  $header = $('#myheader');
  $footer = $('#myfooter');
  $header.detach();
  $footer.detach();
  $header.prependTo(topageid);
  $footer.appendTo(topageid);
 });
```

The source code shown above works sometimes, sometimes not. That's because from time to time `data.toPage` contains only an url like `...index.html#mypage`.
How to detect the id of the `toPage` in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pagebeforeshow` event rather than the `pagebeforechange` event. The difference is that the former fires after external pages have been added to the DOM and the latter fires before that occurs.

There are other page-events that could work for you: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

From the documentation (linked-to above):

> **pagebeforechange**
>
> This event is triggered prior to any page loading or
>   transition.

.

> **pagebeforeshow**
>
> Triggered on the "toPage" we are transitioning to,
>   before the actual transition animation is kicked off.

Answer (score 0):

The `pagebeforechange` event is fired twice, the first time it is fired before the destination page is loaded, that's when you get `data.toPage` containing an URL.
The second time the event is fired the destination page is loaded, in that case you will get a query object containing the page DOM in `data.toPage`.
If you want to stick to the `pagebeforechange` event then you can do something like :

```
if (typeof data.toPage != "string") {
    ... Do your stuff ...
}
```

If you are flexible about the event you want to use then follow Jasper advice and use pagebeforeshow which will allow you to modify your detination page DOM before the page is transitioned to.